# I need to use build trigger to a multibranch pipeline to run

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

In Jenkins, I have a pipeline job called build-job.  I am using the "Build Triggers" section of the job configuration UI to trigger the build-job to run "Build after other projects are Built."  The "Projects to watch" include a job called hygiene-job which is a multibranch pipeline.  I would like the build-job to be triggered after any change is made to any branch (or branch added) but it seems I cannot use regular expressions in the "Projects to watch" field, instead it only lets me use the explicit name of the branch (for example):

`hygiene-job/develop`

`hygiene-job/feature-branch`

`hygiene-job/master`

Ideally I would like to use:

`hygiene-job/*`

but it doesn't seem to like the regex.  Any ideas how to work through this issue?  Maybe a plugin?